# POO and STL vector (Adding an object to a variable)

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


class Empleado {
    private:

        string m_nombre;
        string m_provincia;
        string m_trabajo;
        int m_ID;

    public:
        void ImprimirInfo();
        void Toma_Nombre( string nombre ) { m_nombre = nombre ;}
        void Toma_Provincia( string  provincia) { m_provincia = provincia ;}
        void Toma_Trabajo ( string trabajo ) { m_trabajo = trabajo ;}
        void Toma_ID ( int ID ) { m_ID = ID ;}
        string Dame_Nombre( ){ return m_nombre ;}
        string Dame_Provincia( ){ return m_provincia ;}
        string Dame_Trabajo( ){ return m_trabajo ;}
        int Dame_ID( ){ return m_ID ;}
};


void Empleado::ImprimirInfo( )
{
   cout << "Nombre: " << m_nombre << '\n';
   cout << "Provincia: " << m_provincia << '\n';
   cout << "Puesto: " << m_trabajo << '\n';
   cout << "Salario: " << m_ID << '\n';
}
Empleado Agregar_Nuevo()
{
    Empleado nuevo_empleado;
    string name;
    string state;
    string job;
    int identification;


    cout<<"\nIngrese su nombre: ";
    scanf("%s",&name);
    cout<<"\nIngrese su provincia: ";
    scanf("%s",&state);
    cout<<"\nIngrese su puesto: ";
    scanf("%s",&job);
    cout<<"\nIngrese su ID: ";
    scanf("%d",&identification);


    nuevo_empleado.Toma_ID(identification);
    nuevo_empleado.Toma_Nombre(name);
    nuevo_empleado.Toma_Provincia(state);
    nuevo_empleado.Toma_Trabajo(job);

    return nuevo_empleado;
}

int main()
{
    string name;
    string state;
    string job;
    int identification=0;

    Empleado new_empleado;

    vector <Empleado> v;

    int menu=0;

    while (menu!=6)
    {
        cout<<"-------Menu Principal------\n"<<endl;//just a menu
        cout<<"1.Agregar Empleado"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Eliminar Empleado"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Modificar Empleado"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.Imprimir Empleado"<<endl;
        cout<<"5.Imprimir todos los empleados"<<endl;
        cout<<"6.Salir"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n En que opcion desea Ingresar: ";
        cin>>menu;
        switch(menu)
        {
        case 1:
            new_empleado=Agregar_Nuevo();// I think here is the problem
            cout<<"H"<<endl;
            v.push_back(new_empleado);
            cout<<"Agregado con exito"<<endl;
            break;
        case 2:

            cout<<"\nIngrese el ID a eliminar: ";
            scanf("%d",&identification);
            for (int i=0;i< v.size();i++)
            {
                v.at(i).ImprimirInfo();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"Modificar Empleado"<<endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            /*nuevo_empleado.Dame_Nombre();*/
            break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
    cin.get();
}
```

Ok people, I'm new at programming in C++. I have a doubt with a method called AgregarEmpleados() or something like that. I've been trying to resolve this for a long time without results. I made a double line comment that says "I think here is the problem." where I believe the problem is.

Comment: Please create a minimalistic compilable example with your problem use case and post that example here.

Comment: 1) First thing, if you have code to share, please post the code along with the question here itself.. don't make user download it from third party sites. 2) If you share code, share only relevant parts of it, dont put entire file 3) Try to put some efforts behind the question if you wan't answer..

Comment: @Cœur Please don't bump old, closed, dead questions with trivial edits.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right, I'm sorry, maybe best to delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't read a `std::string` using `scanf`. `scanf("%s", ...)` expects a `char*` and you can't simply pass a pointer to `std::string`, it's a very different data structure. A quick fix would be to change the lines that look like this:

```
scanf("%s",&name);
```

to this:

```
std::cin >> name;
```

or this:

```
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Comment: Blastfurnace it works thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarianoMonteroMuñoz: You're welcome. If you're learning `C++` it's best to stick with `C++` style I/O and not mix in `C` functions like `printf`, `scanf`, etc.

Comment: thanks again and I'll apply your recomendations!